# R plotly, have different color and z-axis on 3D heatmap

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap, r-plotly

I want to plot a 3D heatmap with `plotly` but I would like to have the color gradient independent of the z-axis.

With `ggplot2` I can produce the following image:

```
dat <- data.frame("cat1" = sort(rep(seq(1:6), 6)),
                  "cat2" = rep(seq(1:6), 6),
                  "variable" = round(rnorm(36), 1),
                  "freq" = seq(100, (100-35)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(dat), aes(cat1, cat2, fill = variable, label = freq)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

And now with `plotly`, I'm unable to have the height related to one column (here `freq`) and the color to another one (column `variable`). The following image relates both height and color to `freq`.

```
library(plotly)
mat <- tapply(dat$freq, list(dat$cat1, dat$cat2), sum)
plot_ly(z = ~ mat) %>% add_surface
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @MLavoie suggestion, I found a way to decorrelate color and height of the 3D `heatmap`.

```
dat <- data.frame("cat1" = sort(rep(seq(1:6), 6)),
                  "cat2" = rep(seq(1:6), 6),
                  "variable" = round(rnorm(36), 1),
                  "freq" = seq(100, (100-35)))
library(plotly)
mat <- tapply(dat$freq, list(dat$cat1, dat$cat2), sum)
mat_col <- tapply(dat$variable, list(dat$cat1, dat$cat2), sum)

plot_ly(z = ~ mat, type = "surface", surfacecolor = mat_col)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
plot_ly(z=~mat, type="surface", surfacecolor = matrix(nrow = 6, ncol = 6, rep(1:6, each = 6))
```

I think with `surfacecolor` you can get what you want.